# Hibernate делает разную структуру таблиц

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, hibernate

Есть класс entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="data_mapper")
public class DataMapper {
    
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "DataMapperGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "DataMapperGenerator", sequenceName = "DATA_MAPPER_ID") 
    private Integer id;
    
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name="name", unique = true)
    private String name;
    
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;
     
    @Getter
    @Embedded
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "data_mapper__definition")
    private Map<String, DataDefinition> dataDefinitions=new HashMap();
    ...
}
```

и класс embeddable:

```
@Embeddable
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class DataDefinition{
    
    public static enum DataType{
        STRING,
        BOOLEAN,
        DOUBLE,
        LONG,
        VOID
    }
    
    @Column(name="field")
    private String field;
    
    @Column(name="type")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private DataType type;
}
```

который выступает в качестве значения Map в entity.

БД Postgresql
Создаю чистую базу на одной машине (Win7)
Запускаю собранный проект, получаю:

```
CREATE TABLE public.data_mapper__definition
(
    data_mapper_id integer NOT NULL,
    field character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    type character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    hash integer NOT NULL,
    value character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT data_mapper_definitions_pkey PRIMARY KEY (data_mapper_id, hash, value),
    CONSTRAINT fkaafs5xfb22lsemqus8s0fprd6 FOREIGN KEY (data_mapper_id)
        REFERENCES public.data_mapper (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT fknryw7bseacxjmo5wtsdcuvyey FOREIGN KEY (data_mapper_id)
        REFERENCES public.data_mapper (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Запускаю этот же проект на другой машине (Win10), получаю такую структуру:

```
CREATE TABLE public.data_mapper__definition
(
    data_mapper_id integer NOT NULL,
    field character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    type character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    coder smallint NOT NULL,
    hash integer NOT NULL,
    value bytea NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT data_mapper__definition_pkey PRIMARY KEY (data_mapper_id, coder, hash, value),
    CONSTRAINT fkaafs5xfb22lsemqus8s0fprd6 FOREIGN KEY (data_mapper_id)
        REFERENCES public.data_mapper (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

То есть, во втором случае ключ String от Map из character varying(255) превращается в binary data и ещё добавляется столбец coder.

Работает всё и там и там, данные вставляются и достаются, только совсем в разном виде. А мне надо перенести базу из одной машины на другую.

pom:

```
...
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
</dependency> 
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
   <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
   <version>42.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
   <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
...
```

Версия Postgresql и там и там одинаковая (10.6.1)
Не могу понять, почему hibernate так делает и как его заставить хранить значение ключа Map гарантированно в виде varchar
Помогите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему. Ещё раз перечитал доки по hibernate и всё наладилось:) Убрал @Embedded и добавил @MapKeyColumn.
До этого, похоже, hibernate пытался найти для String @Embeddable класс и творил непонятно что, т.к. не знал, как себя вести с тем набором аннотаций и типом ключа Map, которые я ему написал, хотя, кто знает, что он пытался и от чего у него зависел механизм построения структуры таблицы, но косяк был в неправильных аннотациях. Теперь вот так

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@MapKeyColumn(name="value")
@CollectionTable(name = "data_mapper__definition")
private Map<String, DataDefinition> dataDefinitions=new HashMap();
```

Hibernate создаёт таблицу с колонками data_mapper_id, field, type, value. Удалил колонку hash в заполненной бд, поправил primary key, перенёс на новую машину и всё заработало.